# how to model relation between entity to cover distance between point to point

Tags: database-design, architecture, software-design

I'm building system where I will have something like map. You can create a `Route`, each `Route` has 2 or more `Point`. each `Point` is in specific order 1,2,3,4,...n

Now I want to set distance between points. For example, I want to set that distance between `Point` 1 and 2 is 2 meters, and between 2 and 3 is 4 meters. I'm wondering how should I model it ? I think that I need associative table where I will keep relation to two points and distance between them. Is that correct way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this is to have associative table(as you mentioned).
You will have database which looks, roughly speaking, like this: table Routes(Route_ID, Point_ID, Order), table Distances(From, To, Distance). Where From and To foreign keys to Point_ID.

[image: Roughed out some quick diagram]

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need additional table, while the points lays on the path, you can just create field `distanceToNext` (or `distanceFromPrev`) and store the values here.

This way you can count distance any two points on the path just by summarizing the values.

SQL pseudo code:

```
SELECT SUM(distance) FROM points WHERE id >= 1 AND id <= 100
```

Comment: That will work only as long as there is only one path.

Comment: That's a pseudo code Jim, I assume that there will be some `path_id` field as well...